# Cannot set maximum size for JFrame (under Windows)

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to limit the maximum size of a `JFrame`. However, **this works only under Linux**. Under Windows, the `JFrame` is freely resized. The code is pretty simple:

```
public class TestMaxSize extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public TestMaxSize() {
        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 400));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setMaximizedBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(0, 0, 400, 400));
        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 400));
        setVisible(true);
    }                     
    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        new TestMaxSize();
    }                  
}
```

Comment: Note: there is also `setResizable(false);` if you want to stop it being resized.

Comment: @BeUndead I want to keep it resizable but I want to limit its width.

Comment: Did you consider adding a listener so when the window is resized to be larger you keep the size within the maximum? Why do you need the size to be limited, would making the size of the content pane a maximum suffice? your example works fine on osx.

Comment: @matt I've thought about adding resize listener. However, this seemed cumbersome. I am wondering why the built-in setMaximumSize doesn't work?!
I need to limit the size as the frame seems ugly when it is widened too much.

Comment: I would chalk it up to a limitation of being cross-platform. When you say the frame seems ugly, is it because of the layout changes? It seems like you can have a layout that has a maximum size and when you expand past that there will be a border that might be ugly, but at least still functional.

Answer (score 2):

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setMaximizedBounds-java.awt.Rectangle-) of method `setMaximizedBounds`

> Note, the given maximized bounds are used as a hint for the native system, because the underlying platform may not support setting the location and/or size of the maximized windows. If that is the case, the provided values do not affect the appearance of the frame in the maximized state.

Although `JFrame` extends `java.awt.Component` it is not the same as `JPanel`, for example. You will notice that its superclass, `java.awt.Window`, overrides method `setMinimumSize`. Class `Window` interacts with the window manager of the host operating system. Hence limiting the maximum size of a `Window` needs to be supported by that window manager. On the Windows platform, it appears that this is not a simple thing to do. I could only find an old, third party utility that allows you to configure a maximum size for all windows. Refer to this Web page: [Change The Maximum Window Size](https://www.ghacks.net/2010/08/25/change-the-maximize-window-size/) from nearly seven years ago.

Comment: But setMaximumSize should limit the size. Shouldn't it?

Comment: The `setMaximumSize(...)` method is used as a suggestion for layout managers. Layout managers can choose to respect or ignore this value. I guess the resizing of the frame ignores this value.