# Is there a way to restrict the resize ability of a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a GUI application with Swing and I want to restrict the user from resizing the Frame beyond 400x200. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Apparently not. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65524291/cannot-set-maximum-size-for-jframe-under-windows In any case restrictions like this annoy me. As a user I want to be in control of my desktop. It should not matter to you that the frame is resized to a larger value. You can always use `setResizable( false)` to take away all control from the user.